# script backup namespace,deployment etc.. from kubernetes

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm **looking** for a **bash script** that could **backup all** the **kubernetes** in a **yaml format** or **json** it's good too:) 
I already backup the kubernetes conf files already.

```
/etc/kubernetes
/etc/systemd/system/system/kubelet.service.d
```

etc...

Now I'm just looking to save the

**namespaces**

**deployment**

etc...

Answer (score 5):

You can dump your entire cluster info into one file using:

```
kubectl cluster-info dump > cluster_dump.txt
```

The above command will dump all the yaml and container logs into one file

Or if you just want yaml files, you can write a script of some commands which includes

```
kubectl get deployment -o yaml > deployment.yaml
kubectl get statefulset -o yaml > statefulset.yaml
kubectl get daemonset -o yaml > daemonset.yaml
```

Then you have to keep the namespace also in mind while creating the script. This gives you fair idea what to do

Answer (score 1):

try the below command. you can include all the namespaces that you want to backup

```
mkdir -p /root/k8s-backup

kubectl cluster-info dump --namespaces default,kube-system  --output-directory=/root/k8s-backup
```